# Kotlin JSR223 engine passing bindings

Tags: kotlin, jsr223

I'm trying to pass a value to my kotlin script on JSR223 engine, but it doesn't gets the bindings.

```
class Script<C : ScriptContext>(val scriptClass : KClass<C>, val script : String?) {
    fun execute(context : C) {
        if (script != null) {
            System.setProperty("idea.use.native.fs.for.win", "false")
            val scriptWithContext = """
                import ${scriptClass.java.canonicalName}

                println(ctx)
            """.trimIndent()
            with(ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("kts")) {
                val c = SimpleScriptContext()
                c.setAttribute("ctx", context, javax.script.ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE)
                eval(scriptWithContext, c)
            }

        }
    }    
}
```

It throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: error: unresolved reference: ctx
                println(ctx)
                        ^

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compileAndEval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.eval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:31)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
...
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3):

Direct mapping of the bindings variables is not supported yet. There is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15125) about it.
For now, you can access the variables via the `bindings` map:

`println(bindings["ctx"])`

Comment: UPDATE: Since Kotlin 1.3.50, bindings are working as they meant to be, no bindings[] reference needed!

Comment: @Balage1551 can you explain? I'm failing to use bindings in JMeter's JSR223

Comment: @Balage1551 I'm facing the issue on Kotlin-1.4.21 :-(. Probably I have to configure something. What javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory do you use, and what dependencies?